# Pulling data from pdf to Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a more than 1000 pdf files and I want to extract/pull data from pdf. If I use the pdf to excel conversion then it will take long time so I am trying pull data from pdf to excel using vba.

The format in PDF are as follows :
                                                   Year  20XX
                                                   Month MAR

Unique Identification Number(UIN)
Name of the Company

Particulars       Value             IncomeTax      IndirectTax    OtheTaxes
Sales             20000               1000          10000          500
Purchases         20000               500           500             0
Exempt            3000                 0             0              0

The format in which I require in Excel is as follows :

Year Month UIN NameofthCompany Particularss Value IncomeTax Indirect  OtherTaxes

Comment: And what is your problem? I suggest that read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

There are tools online that do this for you.  Also, if you want to consider converting all PDF files in a folder to text files, you can easily import text all text files into a folder into Excel, and then manipulate any way you want.  A PDF file is essentially a text file, on steroids.  Post back if you have additional questions.

How to import multiple text files from a folder into one worksheet?

```
Sub Test()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice6/7/2016
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xToBook As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xFiles As New Collection
    Dim I As Long
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [Kutools for Excel]"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Right(xStrPath, 1) <> "\" Then xStrPath = xStrPath & "\"
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "*.txt")
    If xFile = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Do While xFile <> ""
        xFiles.Add xFile, xFile
        xFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Set xToBook = ThisWorkbook
    If xFiles.Count > 0 Then
        For I = 1 To xFiles.Count
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & xFiles.Item(I))
            xWb.Worksheets(1).Copy after:=xToBook.Sheets(xToBook.Sheets.Count)
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Name = xWb.Name
            On Error GoTo 0
            xWb.Close False
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but when i converted pdf to text and then imported into excel however its not working .can u please give me step by step guide if possible ?

Comment: Well, a PDF is a beautified text file.  After you convert the PDF to a simple text file, if the raw text is not in user-friendly format, like a table with columns and rows, you'll have to do a bit more work to parse through the text and get what you want.

Comment: I m not able to do it,anyways leave the above question. I hv 1 more question if I convert PDF to excel n then I m trying to write the vba code based on criteria for example, if my company name is Y and the purchase is 200 taxes is 30 then this data is to be copied in another workbook based on company name with the same row name as purchases. Want vba code for these ?